# Relative path in Xlwings Pythonpath

Tags: xlwings

Is it possible to reference the python code in the parent folder of the current folder like this:

```
PYTHONPATH = "../../Python_Code"
```

It won't work on my computer.
The objective is to avoid hard coded paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can set this like so:

`PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/.."`

You might need at least v0.7.0 though.

Comment: @LoveToCode this was dropped with the introduction of the add-in, but is waiting for implementation: You can track this issue https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/883